# Rails has_many_through save additional attribute in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Item model:

```
  has_many :item_locations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :item_locations
```

Location model:

```
  has_many :item_locations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :item_locations
```

ItemLocations:

```
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :location
```

In items_controller I create a new item for a location as follows:

```
@item = Item.new(item_params)
@location = .....
    if @item.save
      @location.items << @item
```

Which creates a record in items and one record in item_location tables.

Assuming I have different item price for different locations, hence a column price in item_locations, how would I set the price of an item for each location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@item.save && item.item_locations.create(:location => @location, :price =>500)
```

This would work for your use case.